# Where do I implement token based authentication in node?

Tags: node.js, api

I´m starting with node and I´ve recently created an API to be consumed by a client app. I´m wondering where I can implement token based authentication, on the server side, client side, or both?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Start here with [Passport](http://passportjs.org/). It supports many different auth types and providers.